# Exporting R output into Latex - Stargazer for non suported objects

Tags: r, latex, stargazer, texreg

I'm estimating models in R using the `frontier` package and I need to export the results into Latex. The output is quite similar to a `lm` regression [see below] but `frontier` objects are not supported by `stargazer` to export them into `Latex` code. Is there any way to work around this? Any idea? 
*I am also looking into `texreg` and `apsrtable`, so far unsuccessfully.

Example of `frontier` regression output:

[image]

Comment: Look at my answer here for a tutorial on how to do this with ``texreg``: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894044/print-beautiful-tables-for-h2o-models-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about getting `stargazer` to output unsupported models, but you can use a`tidy` method from the broom package to get the basic output into a format compatible with `xtable`, `knitr::kable`, or `pixiedust`

```
library(broom)
library(frontier)

# example included in FRONTIER 4.1 (cross-section data)
data( front41Data )

# Cobb-Douglas production frontier
cobbDouglas <- sfa( log( output ) ~ log( capital ) + log( labour ),
                    data = front41Data )
tidy(cobbDouglas, conf.int = TRUE)
broom:::tidy.lm(cobbDouglas)

          term  estimate  std.error statistic      p.value
1  (Intercept) 0.5616193 0.20261685  2.771829 5.574228e-03
2 log(capital) 0.2811022 0.04764337  5.900132 3.632107e-09
3  log(labour) 0.5364798 0.04525156 11.855499 2.015196e-32
4      sigmaSq 0.2170003 0.06390907  3.395454 6.851493e-04
5        gamma 0.7972069 0.13642438  5.843581 5.109042e-09
```

For the summary statistics, you would need to write your own `glance` method, as the `frontier` objects aren't compatible with `broom:::glance.lm`.

But I think the end story is that, if you want to mimic the stargazer output,  you'll have to do some preprocessing work.

And since I'm feeling ambitious today, here's a `tidy` method for frontier objects.

```
tidy.frontier <- function(x, conf.int = FALSE, conf.level = .95,
                          exponentiate = FALSE, quick = FALSE, ...)
{
  broom:::tidy.lm(x, conf.int = conf.int, conf.level = conf.level,
                  exponentiate = exponentiate, quick = quick, ...)
}


# example included in FRONTIER 4.1 (cross-section data)
data( front41Data )

# Cobb-Douglas production frontier
cobbDouglas <- sfa( log( output ) ~ log( capital ) + log( labour ),
                    data = front41Data )
tidy(cobbDouglas, conf.int = TRUE)
```