# Computing p.values in spatial econometric models: why are there inconsistencies between summary() and texreg()?

Tags: r, spatial, p-value, texreg

I am estimating some spatial econometric models that contain both a spatial autoregressive term rho and a spatial error term lambda. In attempting to communicate my results I was using the `texreg` package, which accepts the `sacsarlm` models I am working with. I noticed, however, that `texreg` is printing p-values for the rho and lambda parameters that are identical. `Texreg` appears to be returning the p-value found in the `model@LR1$p.value` slot of the model object.

The parameters rho and lambda are different in magnitude and have different standard errors so they should not have equivalent p-values. If I call summary on the model object I get unique p-values, but cannot figure out where those values are stored within the model object despite going through each element in a `str(model)` call.

My question is twofold:

1. Am I correct in thinking this is an error in the texreg (and screenreg etc.) function or am I erring in my interpretation?
2. How do I compute the correct p-value or find it in the model object (I am writing a new extract function for texreg and need to find the correct value)?

Below is a minimal example that shows the problem:

```
library(spdep)
library(texreg)
set.seed(42)
W.ran <- matrix(rbinom(100*100, 1, .3),nrow=100)
X <- rnorm(100)
Y <- .2 * X + rnorm(100) + .9*(W.ran %*% X)

W.test <- mat2listw(W.ran)
model <- sacsarlm(Y~X, type = "sacmixed",
                listw=W.test, zero.policy=TRUE)
summary(model)

Call:sacsarlm(formula = Y ~ X, listw = W.test, type = "sacmixed", 
    zero.policy = TRUE)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-2.379283 -0.750922  0.036044  0.675951  2.577148 

Type: sacmixed 
Coefficients: (asymptotic standard errors) 
                   Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)      0.91037455  0.65700059  1.3857   0.1659
X               -0.00076362  0.10330510 -0.0074   0.9941
lag.(Intercept) -0.03193863  0.02310075 -1.3826   0.1668
lag.X            0.89764491  0.02231353 40.2287   <2e-16

Rho: -0.0028541
Asymptotic standard error: 0.0059647
    z-value: -0.47849, p-value: 0.6323
Lambda: -0.020578
Asymptotic standard error: 0.020057
    z-value: -1.026, p-value: 0.3049

LR test value: 288.74, p-value: < 2.22e-16

Log likelihood: -145.4423 for sacmixed model
ML residual variance (sigma squared): 1.0851, (sigma: 1.0417)
Number of observations: 100 
Number of parameters estimated: 7 
AIC: 304.88, (AIC for lm: 585.63)

screenreg(model)

=================================
                      Model 1    
---------------------------------
(Intercept)              0.91    
                        (0.66)   
X                       -0.00    
                        (0.10)   
lag.(Intercept)         -0.03    
                        (0.02)   
lag.X                    0.90 ***
                        (0.02)   
---------------------------------
Num. obs.              100       
Parameters               7       
AIC (Linear model)     585.63    
AIC (Spatial model)    304.88    
Log Likelihood        -145.44    
Wald test: statistic     1.05    
Wald test: p-value       0.90    
Lambda: statistic       -0.02    
Lambda: p-value          0.00    
Rho: statistic          -0.00    
Rho: p-value             0.00    
=================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Obviously, in the example, Rho and Lambda have different p-values neither of which are zero and thus there is a problem with the texreg output. Any help with why this is occurring or where to obtain the correct p-values much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, sometime R is a bit obscure - when you call summary, chances are that the values you are interested in are not extracted from the mode object, but calculated at that moment by the summary function. This is not a complete answer, but you should check out the `broom` package, which can provide important model information in a easy-to-use data.frame (usually incl. p values etc.)

Comment: why not just manually replace the values in the `texreg` output? It spits out latex or html afterall...

Comment: I'll take a look at the broom package ,thanks @jakub. I'm producing the latex output from texreg inside a sweave document that is being knit into the final product, so its not practical to do manual editing of the latex.

Comment: According to the full list at https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom, ``broom`` does not support these objects yet. I like the concept of ``broom``, but I think ``texreg``'s concept of the generic ``extract`` function is kind of the same thing, with the main difference being that the extracted output is handed over to several functions for creating regression tables (in ``texreg``), rather than data frames (in ``broom``).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`texreg` author here. Thanks for catching this. As described in my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894044/print-beautiful-tables-for-h2o-models-in-r), `texreg` uses `extract` methods to retrieve the relevant information from any of the (currently more than 70 supported) model object types. It looks like there is a glitch in the GOF part of the method for `sarlm` objects.

Here is what the method currently looks like (as of `texreg` 1.36.13):

```
# extension for sarlm objects (spdep package)
extract.sarlm <- function(model, include.nobs = TRUE, include.aic = TRUE, 
    include.loglik = TRUE, include.wald = TRUE, include.lambda = TRUE, 
    include.rho = TRUE, ...) {
  s <- summary(model, ...)

  names <- rownames(s$Coef)
  cf <- s$Coef[, 1]
  se <- s$Coef[, 2]
  p <- s$Coef[, ncol(s$Coef)]

  gof <- numeric()
  gof.names <- character()
  gof.decimal <- logical()

  if (include.nobs == TRUE) {
    n <- length(s$fitted.values)
    param <- s$parameters
    gof <- c(gof, n, param)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Num.\ obs.", "Parameters")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, FALSE, FALSE)
  }
  if (include.aic == TRUE) {
    aic <- AIC(model)
    aiclm <- s$AIC_lm.model
    gof <- c(gof, aiclm, aic)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "AIC (Linear model)", "AIC (Spatial model)")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)
  }
  if (include.loglik == TRUE) {
    ll <- s$LL
    gof <- c(gof, ll)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Log Likelihood")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE)
  }
  if (include.wald == TRUE) {
    waldstat <- s$Wald1$statistic
    waldp <- s$Wald1$p.value
    gof <- c(gof, waldstat, waldp)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Wald test: statistic", "Wald test: p-value")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)
  }
  if (include.lambda == TRUE && !is.null(s$lambda)) {
    lambda <- s$lambda
    LRpval <- s$LR1$p.value[1]
    gof <- c(gof, lambda, LRpval)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Lambda: statistic", "Lambda: p-value")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)
  }
  if (include.rho == TRUE && !is.null(s$rho)) {
    rho <- s$rho
    LRpval <- s$LR1$p.value[1]
    gof <- c(gof, rho, LRpval)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Rho: statistic", "Rho: p-value")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)
  }

  tr <- createTexreg(
      coef.names = names, 
      coef = cf, 
      se = se, 
      pvalues = p, 
      gof.names = gof.names, 
      gof = gof, 
      gof.decimal = gof.decimal
  )
  return(tr)
}

setMethod("extract", signature = className("sarlm", "spdep"), 
    definition = extract.sarlm)
```

I think you are right that the lambda and rho parts need some updating. The `sacsarlm` function does not store the results printed by its `summary` method in any object, so you are rightly pointing out that any attempts using `str` do not appear to show the true p-values etc.

Therefore it makes sense to take a look at what the `print.summary.sarlm` function in the `spdep` package actually does when it prints the summary. I found the code for this function in the file `R/summary.spsarlm.R` in the [source code of the package on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=spdep). It looks like this:

```
print.summary.sarlm <- function(x, digits = max(5, .Options$digits - 3),
    signif.stars = FALSE, ...)
{
    cat("\nCall:", deparse(x$call), sep = "", fill=TRUE)
       if (x$type == "error") if (isTRUE(all.equal(x$lambda, x$interval[1])) ||
            isTRUE(all.equal(x$lambda, x$interval[2]))) 
            warning("lambda on interval bound - results should not be used")
       if (x$type == "lag" || x$type == "mixed")
            if (isTRUE(all.equal(x$rho, x$interval[1])) ||
            isTRUE(all.equal(x$rho, x$interval[2]))) 
            warning("rho on interval bound - results should not be used")
    cat("\nResiduals:\n")
    resid <- residuals(x)
    nam <- c("Min", "1Q", "Median", "3Q", "Max")
    rq <- if (length(dim(resid)) == 2L) 
        structure(apply(t(resid), 1, quantile), dimnames = list(nam, 
            dimnames(resid)[[2]]))
    else structure(quantile(resid), names = nam)
    print(rq, digits = digits, ...)
    cat("\nType:", x$type, "\n")
    if (x$zero.policy) {
        zero.regs <- attr(x, "zero.regs")
        if (!is.null(zero.regs))
            cat("Regions with no neighbours included:\n",
            zero.regs, "\n")
    }
        if (!is.null(x$coeftitle)) {
        cat("Coefficients:", x$coeftitle, "\n")
        coefs <- x$Coef
        if (!is.null(aliased <- x$aliased) && any(x$aliased)){
        cat("    (", table(aliased)["TRUE"], 
            " not defined because of singularities)\n", sep = "")
        cn <- names(aliased)
        coefs <- matrix(NA, length(aliased), 4, dimnames = list(cn, 
                    colnames(x$Coef)))
                coefs[!aliased, ] <- x$Coef
        }
        printCoefmat(coefs, signif.stars=signif.stars, digits=digits,
        na.print="NA")
    }
#   res <- LR.sarlm(x, x$lm.model)
    res <- x$LR1
        pref <- ifelse(x$ase, "Asymptotic", "Approximate (numerical Hessian)")
    if (x$type == "error") {
        cat("\nLambda: ", format(signif(x$lambda, digits)),
            ", LR test value: ", format(signif(res$statistic,
                        digits)), ", p-value: ", format.pval(res$p.value,
                        digits), "\n", sep="")
        if (!is.null(x$lambda.se)) {
                    if (!is.null(x$adj.se)) {
                        x$lambda.se <- sqrt((x$lambda.se^2)*x$adj.se)   
                    }
            cat(pref, " standard error: ", 
                format(signif(x$lambda.se, digits)),
            ifelse(is.null(x$adj.se), "\n    z-value: ",
                               "\n    t-value: "), format(signif((x$lambda/
                x$lambda.se), digits)),
            ", p-value: ", format.pval(2*(1-pnorm(abs(x$lambda/
                x$lambda.se))), digits), "\n", sep="")
            cat("Wald statistic: ", format(signif(x$Wald1$statistic, 
            digits)), ", p-value: ", format.pval(x$Wald1$p.value, 
            digits), "\n", sep="")
        }
    } else if (x$type == "sac" || x$type == "sacmixed") {
        cat("\nRho: ", format(signif(x$rho, digits)), "\n",
                    sep="")
                if (!is.null(x$rho.se)) {
                    if (!is.null(x$adj.se)) {
                        x$rho.se <- sqrt((x$rho.se^2)*x$adj.se)   
                    }
          cat(pref, " standard error: ", 
            format(signif(x$rho.se, digits)), 
                        ifelse(is.null(x$adj.se), "\n    z-value: ",
                               "\n    t-value: "), 
            format(signif((x$rho/x$rho.se), digits)),
            ", p-value: ", format.pval(2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(x$rho/
                x$rho.se))), digits), "\n", sep="")
                }
        cat("Lambda: ", format(signif(x$lambda, digits)), "\n", sep="")
        if (!is.null(x$lambda.se)) {
                    pref <- ifelse(x$ase, "Asymptotic",
                        "Approximate (numerical Hessian)")
                    if (!is.null(x$adj.se)) {
                        x$lambda.se <- sqrt((x$lambda.se^2)*x$adj.se)   
                    }
            cat(pref, " standard error: ", 
                format(signif(x$lambda.se, digits)),
            ifelse(is.null(x$adj.se), "\n    z-value: ",
                               "\n    t-value: "), format(signif((x$lambda/
                x$lambda.se), digits)),
            ", p-value: ", format.pval(2*(1-pnorm(abs(x$lambda/
                x$lambda.se))), digits), "\n", sep="")
                }
                cat("\nLR test value: ", format(signif(res$statistic, digits)),
            ", p-value: ", format.pval(res$p.value, digits), "\n",
                    sep="")
        } else {
        cat("\nRho: ", format(signif(x$rho, digits)), 
                    ", LR test value: ", format(signif(res$statistic, digits)),
            ", p-value: ", format.pval(res$p.value, digits), "\n",
                    sep="")
                if (!is.null(x$rho.se)) {
                    if (!is.null(x$adj.se)) {
                        x$rho.se <- sqrt((x$rho.se^2)*x$adj.se)   
                    }
          cat(pref, " standard error: ", 
            format(signif(x$rho.se, digits)), 
                        ifelse(is.null(x$adj.se), "\n    z-value: ",
                               "\n    t-value: "), 
            format(signif((x$rho/x$rho.se), digits)),
            ", p-value: ", format.pval(2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(x$rho/
                x$rho.se))), digits), "\n", sep="")
                }
        if (!is.null(x$Wald1)) {
            cat("Wald statistic: ", format(signif(x$Wald1$statistic, 
            digits)), ", p-value: ", format.pval(x$Wald1$p.value, 
            digits), "\n", sep="")
        }

    }
    cat("\nLog likelihood:", logLik(x), "for", x$type, "model\n")
    cat("ML residual variance (sigma squared): ", 
        format(signif(x$s2, digits)), ", (sigma: ", 
        format(signif(sqrt(x$s2), digits)), ")\n", sep="")
        if (!is.null(x$NK)) cat("Nagelkerke pseudo-R-squared:",
            format(signif(x$NK, digits)), "\n")
    cat("Number of observations:", length(x$residuals), "\n")
    cat("Number of parameters estimated:", x$parameters, "\n")
    cat("AIC: ", format(signif(AIC(x), digits)), ", (AIC for lm: ",
        format(signif(x$AIC_lm.model, digits)), ")\n", sep="")
    if (x$type == "error") {
        if (!is.null(x$Haus)) {
            cat("Hausman test: ", format(signif(x$Haus$statistic, 
            digits)), ", df: ", format(x$Haus$parameter),
                        ", p-value: ", format.pval(x$Haus$p.value, digits),
                        "\n", sep="")
        }
        }
    if ((x$type == "lag" || x$type ==  "mixed") && x$ase) {
        cat("LM test for residual autocorrelation\n")
        cat("test value: ", format(signif(x$LMtest, digits)),
            ", p-value: ", format.pval((1 - pchisq(x$LMtest, 1)), 
            digits), "\n", sep="")
    }
        if (x$type != "error" && !is.null(x$LLCoef)) {
        cat("\nCoefficients: (log likelihood/likelihood ratio)\n")
        printCoefmat(x$LLCoef, signif.stars=signif.stars,
            digits=digits, na.print="NA")
        }
        correl <- x$correlation
        if (!is.null(correl)) {
            p <- NCOL(correl)
            if (p > 1) {
                    cat("\n", x$correltext, "\n")
                    correl <- format(round(correl, 2), nsmall = 2, 
                    digits = digits)
                    correl[!lower.tri(correl)] <- ""
                    print(correl[-1, -p, drop = FALSE], quote = FALSE)
                }
        }
        cat("\n")
        invisible(x)
}
```

You can see there that the function first distinguishes between different sub-models (`error` vs. `sac`/`sacmixed` vs. else), then decides which standard errors to use, and then computes the p-values on the fly without saving them anywhere.

So this is what we need to do as well in our `extract` method in order to get the same result as the `summary` method in the `spdep` package. We also need to move this from the GOF block up to the coefficient block of the table (see comments section below for a discussion). Here is my attempt at adopting their approach in the `extract` method:

```
# extension for sarlm objects (spdep package)
extract.sarlm <- function(model, include.nobs = TRUE, include.loglik = TRUE,
    include.aic = TRUE, include.lr = TRUE, include.wald = TRUE, ...) {
  s <- summary(model, ...)

  names <- rownames(s$Coef)
  cf <- s$Coef[, 1]
  se <- s$Coef[, 2]
  p <- s$Coef[, ncol(s$Coef)]

  if (model$type != "error") {  # include coefficient for autocorrelation term
    rho <- model$rho
    cf <- c(cf, rho)
    names <- c(names, "$\\rho$")
    if (!is.null(model$rho.se)) {
      if (!is.null(model$adj.se)) {
        rho.se <- sqrt((model$rho.se^2) * model$adj.se)   
      } else {
        rho.se <- model$rho.se
      }
      rho.pval <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(rho / rho.se)))
      se <- c(se, rho.se)
      p <- c(p, rho.pval)
    } else {
      se <- c(se, NA)
      p <- c(p, NA)
    }
  }

  if (!is.null(model$lambda)) {
    cf <-c(cf, model$lambda)
    names <- c(names, "$\\lambda$")  
    if (!is.null(model$lambda.se)) {
      if (!is.null(model$adj.se)) {
        lambda.se <- sqrt((model$lambda.se^2) * model$adj.se)   
      } else {
        lambda.se <- model$lambda.se
      }
      lambda.pval <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(model$lambda / lambda.se)))
      se <- c(se, lambda.se)
      p <- c(p, lambda.pval)
    } else {
      se <- c(se, NA)
      p <- c(p, NA)
    }
  }

  gof <- numeric()
  gof.names <- character()
  gof.decimal <- logical()

  if (include.nobs == TRUE) {
    n <- length(s$fitted.values)
    param <- s$parameters
    gof <- c(gof, n, param)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Num.\ obs.", "Parameters")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, FALSE, FALSE)
  }
  if (include.loglik == TRUE) {
    ll <- s$LL
    gof <- c(gof, ll)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Log Likelihood")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE)
  }
  if (include.aic == TRUE) {
    aic <- AIC(model)
    aiclm <- s$AIC_lm.model
    gof <- c(gof, aiclm, aic)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "AIC (Linear model)", "AIC (Spatial model)")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)
  }
  if (include.lr == TRUE && !is.null(s$LR1)) {
    gof <- c(gof, s$LR1$statistic[[1]], s$LR1$p.value[[1]])
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "LR test: statistic", "LR test: p-value")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)
  }
  if (include.wald == TRUE && !is.null(model$Wald1)) {
    waldstat <- model$Wald1$statistic
    waldp <- model$Wald1$p.value
    gof <- c(gof, waldstat, waldp)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Wald test: statistic", "Wald test: p-value")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)
  }

  tr <- createTexreg(
      coef.names = names, 
      coef = cf, 
      se = se, 
      pvalues = p, 
      gof.names = gof.names, 
      gof = gof, 
      gof.decimal = gof.decimal
  )
  return(tr)
}

setMethod("extract", signature = className("sarlm", "spdep"), 
    definition = extract.sarlm)
```

You can just execute this code at run-time to update the way `texreg` handles these objects. Please do let me know if you still think there are any glitches I haven't spotted. If none are reported in the comments, I will include this updated `extract` method in the next `texreg` release.

With these changes, calling `screenreg(model, single.row = TRUE)` yields the following output:

```
=======================================
                     Model 1           
---------------------------------------
(Intercept)             0.91 (0.66)    
X                      -0.00 (0.10)    
lag.(Intercept)        -0.03 (0.02)    
lag.X                   0.90 (0.02) ***
rho                    -0.00 (0.01)    
lambda                 -0.02 (0.02)    
---------------------------------------
Num. obs.             100              
Parameters              7              
Log Likelihood       -145.44           
AIC (Linear model)    585.63           
AIC (Spatial model)   304.88           
LR test: statistic    288.74           
LR test: p-value        0.00           
=======================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Comment: This is an incredibly thorough answer, thank you! In fact, I had already written (a much less complete) extract function for the sacsarlm model I was estimating (I wanted some particular changes as well like moving the location of rho and lambda up to the coefficients), and computed p-values in the usual way.  Your idea of looking in the spdep source for exactly what summary was doing (instead of reverse engineering it through guessing) is much more sensible. Also, I think making texreg extensible with the extract function was a great idea and am very grateful to you for writing it that way!

Comment: Glad it helped. What would be the ideal order of items in the GOF block, in your opinion?

Comment: Well, I actually moved Rho and Lambda into the coefficients column at the top. Rho is the primary coefficient of interest in my study, as I'm using it to capture peer effects in a network analysis. This is not an uncommon way to use these models, and if that is the case then you of course want the spatial autocorrelation coefficients to display as coefficients. This is actually how extract.lnam() does it if you use the lnam version of this kind of spatial model from the sna package (its much slower, which is why I use spdep).

Comment: I'm not saying the extract function should necessarily change to work that way. I suspect some researchers are fitting spatial models to control for spatial endogeneity when they are interested in modeling some other relationship, and for them having it as a GOF might make more sense. However, it seems like making rho and lambda coefficients might be more flexible: if you think about them as GOFs its not a big deal if they are displayed as coefficients, but if you are interested in the size of the coefficients its pretty annoying if they are presented as GOF measures. Just my opinion.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I have moved rho and lambda to the coefficient block and updated the answer. It's interesting that you are using ``spdep`` for network analysis. You may also want to take a look at my ``tnam`` package for ``R`` (implementing the Temporal Network Autocorrelation Model). This is an extension of the model you are using to arbitrary kinds of network dependencies as well as panel data (if needed). Besides spatial lags, you can include centrality of nodes, friends' of friends row-normalized behavior at the previous time point, structural similarity, and other dependencies.

Comment: Thank I wasn't aware of that package. I'll take a look.