# Show the Result of Amelia, Multiple Imputation, by texreg or stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer, texreg, r-zelig

I would like to know how to export the outcome of Multiple Imputation `Amelia` summary to tex or html by `texreg` or `stargazer`.
However, both type of packages show the error.

```
library(Amelia)
library(Zelig)
library(texreg)
library(stargazer)

mi <-amelia(x = d,m = 5)
summary(mi)
lmi <- zelig(y ~ x1+x2,
 data = m, model = "logit")
summary(lmi)
mi2 <-amelia(x = d,m = 5)
summary(mi2)
lmi2 <- zelig(y ~ x1+x2,
 data = m2, model = "logit")
summary(lmi2)

stargazer(lmi,lmi2, title="hogehoge", omit.stat=c("f","ser"), align=T, no.space=T)

>Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) :
>‘result’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “Zelig-logit”

models <- list(lmi,lmi2)
texreg(l=models,file="texreg.tex", caption="texreg",
    digits=3, booktabs=T, dcolumn=T, center=T, use.packages=F, caption.above=T, custom.model.names=c("model1", "model2"))

>Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
>unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"Zelig-logit"’
```

How can I show the result of multiple imputation by R?

**P.S.**

```
> summary(lmi)
Model: Combined Imputations 
                    Estimate Std.Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -4.15186   0.41048 -10.1147 0.000e+00 ***
x1                   9.76225   0.18356  12.4336 0.000e+00 ***
x2                   1.76719   0.18031  10.9489 0.000e+00 ***
---
Signif. codes:  '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

For results from individual imputed datasets, use summary(x, subset = i:j)
Next step: Use 'setx' method
```

lmi2 is similar to lmi.

Answer (score 2):

Not all model objects are currently supported in either package, and I guess that is the case for the models you are using. If stargazer does not support your model object I'm not aware of a solution. However, texreg is extensible: you can write a simple function to extract what you need from the model object and then the normal texreg commands will work with that extract function. This is clearly explained in [this article](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/texreg.pdf) on texreg, see section six.

The author of texreg also wrote out an example of how to write an extract function in answer to a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397194/computing-p-values-in-spatial-econometric-models-why-are-there-inconsistencies), and wrote an even more comprehensive review of how to extend texreg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894044/print-beautiful-tables-for-h2o-models-in-r). I would advise you to write extract functions that work with your model objects and then you can use texreg.

Answer (score 0):

texreg now handles Zelig objects and works with Amelia, Mice and Mi through Zelig. Use the function to_zelig_mi to create data object that Zelig will recognize.