# texreg table for impacts of spatial lag model

Tags: r, latex, texreg, spdep, spatial-regression

I am using `spdep` to run a spatial regression using a Durbin lag model. This type of model returns direct, indirect and total effects for each regression coefficient and their level of significance.

Is there an `R` library like [`texreg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/texreg.pdf) that organizes in a nice way the output of a Durbin lag model with information about direct, indirect and total effects?

#### Reproducible example:

```
library(spdep)

example(columbus)
listw <- nb2listw(col.gal.nb)

# spatial regression - Durbin Model
  mobj <- lagsarlm(CRIME ~ INC + HOVAL, columbus, listw, type="mixed")
  summary(mobj)

# Calculate direct and indirect impacts
  W <- as(listw, "CsparseMatrix")
  trMatc <- trW(W, type="mult")
  trMC <- trW(W, type="MC")
  imp <- impacts(mobj, tr=trMC, R=100) 
  sums <- summary(imp, zstats=T)

# Return Effects
  data.frame(sums$res)

# Return p-values
  data.frame(sums$pzmat)
```

Comment: Since you know how to get the information you want from the model object (e.g., coefficients, p-values etc.), you can try to write a `texreg` extension. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894044/) for a related post with instructions. See also section 6 of the [JSS article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v055i08) on `texreg`.

Comment: Linking back to the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/leifeld/texreg/issues/60

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there's an existing function to create a nice looking table for this type of model object, but (with some effort) you can roll your own.

Below is an `rmarkdown` document with your code plus three additional code chunks. The first combines the coefficient and p-value data. The next two generate two different options for `latex` tables.

I used `sums$res` and `sums$pzmat` for the table values, `tidyverse` functions to combine the coefficient estimates and p-values and edit the column names, and the `kable` and `kableExtra` packages to produce the latex output.

#### `rmarkdown` document

````
---
title: "Coefficient Table for Durbin Lag Model"
author: "eipi10"
date: "8/30/2017"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE)

library(spdep)
library(texreg)

example(columbus)
listw <- nb2listw(col.gal.nb)
```

```{r}
# spatial regression - Durbin Model
  mobj <- lagsarlm(CRIME ~ INC + HOVAL, columbus, listw, type="mixed")
  #summary(mobj)

# Calculate direct and indirect impacts
  W <- as(listw, "CsparseMatrix")
  trMatc <- trW(W, type="mult")
  trMC <- trW(W, type="MC")
  imp <- impacts(mobj, tr=trMC, R=100) 
  sums <- summary(imp, zstats=T)

# Return Effects
#  data.frame(sums$res)

# Return p-values
#  data.frame(sums$pzmat)
```

```{r extractTableData}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

# Extract coefficients and p-values
tab = bind_rows(sums$res) %>% t %>% as.data.frame %>% 
  setNames(., names(sums$res[[1]])) %>%
  mutate(Coef_Type=str_to_title(rownames(.)),
         Value_Type="Estimate") %>% 
  bind_rows(sums$pzmat %>% t %>% as.data.frame %>% 
              mutate(Coef_Type=rownames(.),
                     Value_Type="p-value")) %>% 
  gather(key, value, INC, HOVAL) 
```

```{r table1}
# Reshape table into desired output format
tab1 = tab %>% 
  unite(coef, key, Value_Type) %>% 
  spread(coef, value) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 3)

# Change column names to what we want to see in the output table
names(tab1) = c("", gsub(".*_(.*)", "\\1", names(tab1)[-1]))

# Output latex table, including extra header row to mark coefficient names
kable(tab1, booktabs=TRUE, format="latex") %>% 
  add_header_above(setNames(c("", 2, 2), c("", sort(rownames(sums$pzmat))))) %>% 
  kable_styling(position="center")
```

\vspace{1cm}

```{r table2}
# Reshape table into desired output format
tab2 = tab %>% 
  unite(coef, Coef_Type, Value_Type) %>% 
  spread(coef, value) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 3)

# Change column names to what we want to see in the output table
names(tab2) = c("Coefficient", gsub(".*_(.*)", "\\1", names(tab2)[-1]))

# Output latex table, including extra header row to mark coefficient names
kable(tab2, booktabs=TRUE, format="latex") %>% 
  add_header_above(setNames(c(" ", rep(2, 3)), c("", colnames(sums$pzmat)))) %>% 
  kable_styling(position="center")
```
````

---

#### PDF output document

[image]