# Making pretty tables with glmmPQL (MASS) and stargazer/texreg/pander

Tags: r, stargazer, pander, texreg

I generated some GLMMs with glmmpql(Guassian log link) from the MASS package, with the output being:

```
PQL_meth_sLL<- glmmPQL(sLL~Temp_fac*State, ~1|Locality/Family, family=gaussian(link="log"), data=adult, verbose=FALSE)
> class(PQL_meth_sLL)
>> [1] "glmmPQL" "lme"
```

I was hoping to use stargazer to make quick and appealing tables of the output.
But I get that the type is unrecognized even though the output is an lme?

```
stargazer(PQL_meth_sLL,  title= "GLMM results for temperature and state on larvae development", digits=2, align=TRUE)
>>% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

The only package I have gotten to kind of work with glmmPQL models is pander. Stargazer and texreg return errors.

```
texreg(PQL_meth_sLL)
>>Error in validityMethod(object) : 
  gof.names and gof must have the same length!
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Have you tried the instructions provided in my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894044/?