# How do I export results from Marginal effects on Latex using Bife

Tags: r, latex, texreg

I'm estimating a fixed-effects logit model using the bife package in R. I need to estimate the marginal effects of the estimation and export them to latex. However, the package that supports bife estimation, texreg, doesn't allow to export objects of class "bifeAPEs". Is there any solution to this?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
#Require packages
packages<-c("bife", "texreg")
lapply(packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

#Dataset
data("iris")
iris$big <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length > median(iris$Sepal.Length),1,0)

#Model
output <- bife(big ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length | Species, data=iris, "logit")

#Output
apes_stat <- get_APEs(output)
class(apes_stat)
extract(output)
extract(apes_stat)
```

Comment: Hi there. See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894044/print-pretty-tables-for-h2o-models-in-r/39135080#39135080) regarding how to write new extensions for `texreg` and [the code for the existing `bife` extension](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg/blob/92e393131f5d6c0f75fbfc3934567d36032e626a/R/extract.R#L464). Together, this should allow you to change the code to make it work with those model objects. (I would do it but am a bit pressed for time atm.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you can do is create a `data.frame` of the average partial effects and then convert that `data.frame` into a latex table using `xtable`, like below:-

```
ape_data <- data.frame(APES = attr(apes_stat$delta, "names"),
                       delta = unname(apes_stat$delta))
xtab_ape <- xtable::xtable(ape_data)
xtab_ape
```

If you don't want `rownames` to be printed in latex, then you can add the following command:-

```
print(xtab_ape, include.rownames = FALSE)
```