# Texreg: Two models in one Latex table

Tags: r, texreg

I have two BIFE models that do not work with stargazer, unfortunately. The Texreg package allows me to convert it Latex output, but I do not know how to put two models side by side.

The stargazer equivalent would be:

```
stargazer(model1, model2)
```

Comment: What do you want to see in result? Add a simple example.

Comment: By the way, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894044/print-pretty-tables-for-h2o-models-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with:

```
texreg(screenreg(list(model1, model2), custom.note = ""))
```